# django add context based on request to all views

Tags: django

I need to render my site without navbar if there is an argument in the request like nv=false and I want to pass a variable to context based on this so that the main template shows the block or not. my site also has lots of json-rpc functions, and I don't want to add extra overhead on it. how can I do this without rewriting all my views? (they are not class based and my site uses django 1.8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass variables to all templates in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030611/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-all-templates-in-django)

Comment: No, its not, needed to process request and then pass a variable, and context processor did it for me :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add context processor that will add this variable to context. Context processor is a simple python function

```
def navbar(request):
    return {'navbar_enabled': request.GET.get('nv', False)
```

and add it to the list of template context processors

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'MODULE_NAME.navbar',
    ...
)
```

Comment: If you are using the new `TEMPLATES` setting In Django 1.8+,  set the `context_processors` option in the `TEMPLATES` setting, instead of `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: I've got a filter on request that is now broken, my request is an empty string when this filter gets it! whats wrong?

Comment: I've got it, the request object is no longer passed to templates using the new SETTINGS object, I think it should have been pointed out on the docs somewhere https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES

Comment: Others might be curious where a good place to put their custom context processors is.  The pattern I've seen used in Two Scoops is just simply in `<your_app_name>.context_processors`.